# MySQL query to return an avg price per month(get the month out of the date formated 2010-03-30 for example)

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables...

Given the following tables I would like to know how to write a query to return all the book sorted by month and with a 
average price per month table (that would be something like SUM(invoices.total)/COUNT(invoices.total).
I have a date field which has a format of 2010-03-30, and I would like to get the months out of if…so I can sort the sum
by  month. I'm using PHP and MySQL.
Thank you in advance!

**books**

-call_started

**books_chapters**

-id

**invoices**

-id

-invoice_type

-chapters_id

-total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not construct the full query from the schema in your question but you can group the results - `GROUP BY(CONCAT(YEAR(date_field), MONTH(date_field))`

If you elaborate or comment, I will improve my answer.

Comment: Or better with `GROUP BY YEAR(date_field), MONTH(date_field)`. No need to make an additional call to function `CONCAT()`.